# Is having side-effects in constructor an anti-pattern?

Tags: c++, side-effect

I was trying to understand how to embed v8 engine in a C++ application and was trying to understand the following hello world problem as a result.

I found the code to be unreadable at first glance. e.g.

```
v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
```

Here, `handle_scope` is not referenced anywhere at all. But if I remove this line, the code snippet fails. Given I have not dealt with codebases as huge as v8, I am not sure if there is legitimate use-cases for such code patterns. I would have expected a similar side-effect to be expressed through a first class function.

Thoughts?

Full code:

```
// Copyright 2015 the V8 project authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "include/libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "include/v8.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Initialize V8.
  // std::cout << argv[0];
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
      v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

    // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    // Create a new context.
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);

    // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    {
      // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
      v8::Local<v8::String> source =
          v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "'Hello' + ', World!'",
                                  v8::NewStringType::kNormal)
              .ToLocalChecked();

      // Compile the source code.
      v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
          v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

      // Run the script to get the result.
      v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

      // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
      v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
      printf("%s\n", *utf8);
    }

    {
      // Use the JavaScript API to generate a WebAssembly module.
      //
      // |bytes| contains the binary format for the following module:
      //
      //     (func (export "add") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
      //       get_local 0
      //       get_local 1
      //       i32.add)
      //
      const char* csource = R"(
        let bytes = new Uint8Array([
          0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x01,
          0x60, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x07,
          0x07, 0x01, 0x03, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x01,
          0x07, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x20, 0x01, 0x6a, 0x0b
        ]);
        let module = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
        let instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module);
        instance.exports.add(3, 4);
      )";

      // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
      v8::Local<v8::String> source =
          v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, csource, v8::NewStringType::kNormal)
              .ToLocalChecked();

      // Compile the source code.
      v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
          v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

      // Run the script to get the result.
      v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

      // Convert the result to a uint32 and print it.
      uint32_t number = result->Uint32Value(context).ToChecked();
      printf("3 + 4 = %u\n", number);
    }
  }

  // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
  isolate->Dispose();
  v8::V8::Dispose();
  v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
  delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510822/what-is-the-design-rationale-behind-handlescope

Comment: I think the best place for asking about design decisions for a specific software product is the discussion forum of the product. For Google's V8 engine, you find it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/v8-dev).

Comment: This is common in C++. It's called RAII

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am not sure if there is legitimate use-cases for such code patterns.

Yes there are, and such stuff is even used in the c++ standard library.
Prominent examples are the [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) and any kind of [*Smart Pointers*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

The principle always follows this pattern:

1. Create a scope
2. Setup some resource (e.g. a mutex lock) within a constructor function
3. Do something further using the resource setup inside the given scope (directly or implicitely)
4. Release the resource in the destructor function (e.g. unlock the formerly locked mutex), this is automatically called when the scope ends

The advantage of doing this, is to have a guaranteed release of the resource at end of the scope it was aquired in. No matter if the end of scope is reached regularly, or due to exceptions.

So: No, this isn't an anti-pattern.

---

Regarding the specifically mentioned `v8::HandleScope` class, it exactly follows the pattern described above. The [documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d3/d95/classv8_1_1_handle_scope.html) says (emphasis mine):

> > #### Detailed Description
> >
> > ---
> >
> > A **stack-allocated class** that governs a number of local handles. After a handle scope has been created, all local handles will be allocated **within that handle scope** until either the handle scope **is deleted** or another handle scope is created. If there is already a handle scope and a new one is created, all allocations will take place in the new handle scope until it is deleted. After that, new handles will again be allocated in the original handle scope.
> >
> > After the handle scope of a local handle has been deleted the garbage collector will no longer track the object stored in the handle and may deallocate it. The behavior of accessing a handle for which the handle scope has been deleted is undefined.

Comment: Do you mean [RAII](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) ?

Comment: @Christophe RAII is at least strongly related, I already thought about mentioning it.

Comment: This *is* RAII.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Caleth Of course it is, but a specific aspect. Simple data initialization doesn't involve _"side effects"_ as mentioned by the OP.

Comment: I also mean "RAII *is this*". It's an idiom, not an anti-pattern